# How to resolve nested React components into a tree of elements?

Tags: reactjs

I need to resolve all React components into their respective React elements (e.g., type=div,ul,li), including all nested components that there may be. I'm doing it successfully already; however, I'm getting a warning about calling a React component directly. Also, it's quite possible I'm going about it wrong in the first place.

```
function resolveNestedDomElements(reactElement) {
    // is there a better way to check if it's a component?
    if (React.isValidElement(reactElement) && _.isFunction(reactElement.type)) {
        // is there a better way to access a component's children?
        reactElement = reactElement.type(reactElement.props);
        // Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a
        // factory or JSX instead. See https://fb.me/react-legacyfactory
        // Note: Unfortunately, the factory solution doesn't work.
    }
    if (!React.isValidElement(reactElement)) {
        return reactElement;
    }
    let { children } = reactElement.props;
    if (React.Children.count(children)) {
        if (React.isValidElement(children)) {
            children = resolveNestedDomElements(children);
        } else {
            children = React.Children.map(
                children,
                resolveNestedDomElements
            );
        }
    }
    return React.cloneElement(reactElement, reactElement.props, children);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here; this question may be [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But the warning is because you're calling `.type` as a function rather than calling `React.createElement(type, ...)`

Comment: @BinaryMuse but `React.createElement(type, ...)` doesn't actually expose the children to the component, which is what I need. They are hidden and only accessible from within the function call. If you have a better way, it may be all I need to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to for a library I'm writing for serializing react components... reactElement.type(reactElement.props) shows a warning, but doesn't return a value for me. :(

Comment: It seems they had it as a warning for a while, and it now throws an error: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28

Answer (score 1):

Your original code now returns an error in 0.14.7, with no output, from React, containing the same message that used to warn (again, behavior as described in the link provided above).

Updating your code to this, as per [the update here](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28):

```
    function resolveNestedDomElements(reactElement) {
        if (React.isValidElement(reactElement) && typeof reactElement.type === 'function') {
            reactClass = React.createFactory(reactElement.type)
            reactElement = reactClass(Object.assign({},reactElement.props));
            }
        if (!React.isValidElement(reactElement)) {
            return reactElement;
        }
        let { children } = reactElement.props;
        if (React.Children.count(children)) {
            if (React.isValidElement(children)) {
                children = resolveNestedDomElements(children);
            } else {
                children = React.Children.map(
                    children,
                    resolveNestedDomElements
                );
            }
        }
        return React.cloneElement(reactElement, reactElement.props, children);
    }
```

This no longer warns (or, in current versions, it now just returns an error in the original form you posted), but the output is not resolved, either. It's unclear to me why this has changed.

The answer seems to be that it seems impossible to resolve anymore. I can't quite follow what's happening in the React source (I believe the render functions of components eventually are called by ReactDOM.render these days, but how that works is unclear to me still). Calling ReactDOM.render doesn't work without a DOM. There is a react-test-utils.shallowRenderer that looks like it may be helpful, that I need to experiment with.

It's a bit absurd how difficult this is. I'm not sure what architecture decision I'm missing at this point.